# Windows dns messed up

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, dhcp-server

Our small windows domain is based on two old 2003 server which are domain controllers.

They both have dns server and dhcp server running on them. Each dhcp server has its own range of ip addresses in order to avoid any overlap.

Time to time checking the dns I find some inconsistencies: the same ip is associated to different hostnames and the same hostname can have a different ip on the two dns.

I suppose the source of the problem is that when DCHP lease expires the its associated IP can be assigned to a different hostname.

The configuration properties of DHCP and DNS are not too much, I looked at them, but I found nothing which could solve the above problem.

May be I need a better integration between both DHCP, both DNS and Active Directory, but I don't know how to do.

Comment: The problem might be that your second DC is a Read Only DC. You might find an answer to your problem at this [page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4031.how-read-only-domain-controllers-and-dns-works.aspx) where the working of RODC and DNS is explained very well.

Comment: Windows Server 2003 Domain Controllers don't support RODC's. The problem is most likely that you haven't enabled aging and scavenging on the DNS server and the DNS zones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have DNS scavenging on?

[Understanding Aging and Scavenging | Microsoft Docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771677(v=ws.11).aspx)